# When trying to install VS Code command to PATH, I get "EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/usr/loca/bin/code'"

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

Im trying to add the command "code" to my VS code path, however when I try to add it in vs code, I get this message saying EACCES: permission denied. Do you know how I can add this to the path? Also, i'm using a mac. [image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to uninstall the `code` command by running `Shell Command: Uninstall 'code' command from PATH` in the VS Code command palette, and then try installing `code` to the PATH again. ([source](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/129884#issuecomment-895748836)).

If that doesn't work, check the permissions of `/usr/local/bin/code` with `ls -la /usr/local/bin/code`. If the root user owns the file, remove it with `sudo rm /usr/local/bin/code` and then try to add VS Code to the PATH again. ([source](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/154163)).

Comment: Thanks, uninstalled and installed and it works :)